# Is CLI for SAP ABAP Repository available?

Tags: command-line-interface, sapui5, abap

Is there CLI interface to push changes to SAP ABAP repository? So far I only found https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/49/11df10cf292810e10000000a42189c/content.htm and know how to push changes from Eclipse UI (http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-42820). Java API for pushing changing might be an option as well if CLI is not available.

Comment: I do not know of a simple CLI for this, but you could create one fairly simply by writing a Java/C# program that can submit changes via RFC to web-enabled ABAP function modules. I would even venture to guess there are existing function modules for this that could be leveraged.

Comment: Do you mean only UI5 applications or all program types? FMs, includes, programs?

Comment: @Suncatcher I meant UI5 apps, but as this is ABAP repository anything can be stored there. As Stu G mentioned there is a standard RFC for uploading files into ABAP repository, so we managed to write a simple deployment script using Python (same can be done with NodeJS).

Comment: @StuG Thanks for the comment. We found the RFC in managed to push data to ABAP repository programmatically.

Comment: @Fedor did you find some standard RFC? Can you name it?